# What is the junction that connects conduit to a structure called?

Tags: electrical, materials, terminology

Drawing plans and writing a BOM and looking for what that part is called. I brought pictures!

[image]

I don't know the proper term for that part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's officially called a **conduit body**, but is sometimes called an **LB** by tradesmen.

It's known as an "LB", because the outlet (or inlet I guess) is on the back (ell back). There are also "LR" (ell right), "LL" (ell left), "T" (tee), "C" (cee), and "SLB" (service ell back) type conduit bodies available.

[image]

<sup>*SLB not pictured.*</sup>